# Does Robo Monkeys (just darts) or Plasma Vision deal more damage?

Tags: bloons-td-5

The Robo Monkey (0-3) has two separate guns, both shooting darts. It has bigger range because of the two previous upgrades. The Plasma Vision (2-0) has plasma (obviously) but has less range. Which do you think is better? Plasma has more popping power but Robo has two guns, which deal more damage than one. It also has larger range.

(Please consider costs, Robo costs few thousand more)

Comment: Sorry, it's "Does the Robo Monkey" in the title, not "Do the Robo Monkey"

Comment: You can just edit your question by clicking the edit link beneath it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR - Plasma Vision if it's shooting at all.

Obviously this is dependent on whether or not the range of the Plasma Vision Super Monkey covers enough area to be constantly shooting and be somewhat useful.

The Super Monkey upgrade path of 0-3 is generally never ever recommended.

1-0 or 0-1 upgrade path, depending on if you NEED the range upgrade is recommended. Much more popping power this way.

Then 2-0 or 1-1. Plasma is serious popping power. If you can get away with the standard range of the Super Monkey, use the 2-0 path. Only go with the 2-1 path if you NEED the increased range.

Plasma Vision upgrade lets the Super Monkey shoot Plasma Beams, doubles the firing rate, increases popping power by 1 and can pop Lead Bloons. The Robo Upgrade is a standard super monkey x 2, which is no where near the popping power of a single Plasma Vision monkey.

Comment: A [Robo Monkey](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Robo_Monkey) can pop Lead Bloons and has a higher pierce and more range than a 0/2 Super Monkey.

Comment: It just has an increased popping power of 2. A 0-3 upgrade path will not pop lead balloons.

Comment: Yes, it will.  I just tested it in Sandbox mode with a 0/3 Robo Monkey.  Lead Bloons popped.  Or you could click the link that I provided.

Comment: Apparently it can. In the older versions of bloons anything that shot regular darts couldn't pop lead. My bad.

Comment: It wasn't even part of the original BTD5.  In the original version, a 1/3 could but a 0/3 couldn't.  For whatever reason, they decided that the two should have the same behavior.  There were some people who considered it a bug and thought that only a 2+/* should be able to pop lead.

Comment: Ah cool so I'm not crazy then. Yeah I remember having to upgrade to at least lasers to pop leads.